# Firefox won't load a Leaflet map in a dynamically loaded div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, leaflet

I will provide a link to the demo site where the code is at the end of my description.

I am using Jquery to dynamically load a leaflet map from another html file into a div. Everything works perfectly on Chrome, Opera, and Safari browsers but I am running into an issue when it comes to Firefox. The dynamic div content only partially loads. The CSS styling loads but It's missing the map image and data points for the map which is in a separate JS file linked in the html.

you can find the demo site here: http://members.fitletes.com/membersBSS/ Open the slider bar menu on the left click 'CEU Map' menu item.

Again works like a charm in those three browsers just not in firefox. I appreciate any insight as I am new to this whole world of coding.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to provide enough information in your question, including code. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).